# How to use a Series to filter a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Series with the following content.

```
$ import pandas as pd
$ s = pd.Series(
    data = [True, False, True, True],
    index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    )
$ s.index.name = 'my_id'

$ print(s)

my_id
A     True
B    False
C     True
D     True
dtype: bool
```

and a DataFrame like this.

```
$ df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 9, 4],
    'B': [9, 6, 7, 8],
    'C': [10, 91, 32, 13],
    'D': [43, 12, 7, 9]
})

$ print(df)

   A  B   C   D
0  1  9  10  43
1  2  6  91  12
2  9  7  32   7
3  4  8  13   9
```

`s` has `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as its indices. `df` also has `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` as it column names.

`True` in `s` means that the corresponding column in `df` will be preserved. `False` in `s` means that the corresponding column in `df` will be removed.

How can I generate another DataFrame with column B removed using `s`?

I mean I want to create the following DataFrame using `s` and `df`.

```
   A   C   D
0  1  10  43
1  2  91  12
2  9  32   7
3  4  13   9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). The `:` means filter all rows. Columns are filtered by `Series` filled with boolean - `mask`:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, s]
print (df1)

   A   C   D
0  1  10  43
1  2  91  12
2  9  32   7
3  4  13   9
```